# http-proxy-middleware not proxying to index page of other server?

Tags: reactjs, http-proxy-middleware

I have two servers running on Docker. One is the react frontend at `localhost:3000` while the backend runs at `localhost:9000`. When I go to localhost:3000/api, I want to get to the index page of the backend, which is `localhost:9000`.

Created a setupProxy.js file in the myApp folder created through create-react-app:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://backend:9000' }));
};
```

When I go to `localhost:3000/api`, I get sent to `localhost:9000/api` instead of `localhost:9000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http-proxy-middleware` has a `pathRewrite` option, see the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-middleware-options).

In your particular case:

```js
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api', {
    target: 'http://backend:9000',
    pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''}
  }));
};
```

this should normally rewrite `localhost:3000/api/endpoint` to `localhost:9000/endpoint`.

Note that there is also a `router` option for more tailored behavior.